# mysql> error 1265: data truncated for column 'xxx' at row 1

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import a csv file into a table in a mysql database. The table has 141 columns with datatypes of `INT`, `VARCHAR(20)`, `TIMESTAMP`,`TIMESTAMP`, and then a series of `TINYTEXT`s and `VARCHAR(4)`s.

I'm getting 7 data truncated errors on columns with datatype `VARCHAR(4)` for which the data does **not** exceed 4 characters.

I tried forcing it to continue with `IGNORE`, but then it went crazy and chopped data from *other* cells into pieces and scattered them throughout the table.

I'm using the command-line on an MS 2008 R2 Server to run the SQL and the csv file is located in the Db's directory.

P.S. I did read several of the other posts and google results related to mysql+import or mysql+data truncated (1265), but they didn't seem to cover this particular issue.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `LOAD DATA` function because if I `INSERT` one row at a time, it works just fine…

My sql for the import is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '2011-09.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE `survey`.`2011-09` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: 100+ varchar/text columns, what you are storing in this table? Smells like bad DB design

Comment: results from a 120-question survey. they previously had a table with 628 text columns; needless to say there was a lot of crap.

Comment: What is the character encoding being used for the VARCHAR columns?

Comment: Also a column per question sounds odd/code smell. You may see some benefit to have one row per question in a separate questions table in the DB. If you are refactoring, now may be a good time to make significant changes. Just a thought.

Comment: UTF8 (same as the table default)

Comment: Why would I do break it apart like that? Sounds like a lot of needless overhead…
Currently it's set up that the DB is for the survey, tables are per month, columns are per question, and rows are per response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During an `INSERT`, MySQL will tell you if you have too many columns. But apparently MySQL is not very kind: during a `LOAD` it does ***not*** tell you if you have too many columns.